# Extract data between br Tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

how can I extract `INFO1` and `INFO2` from following html code with beautifulsoup?

> webiste: https://swisswrestling.ch/wrestlers?id=91

I try also to extract data for the fights but that works for me with bs4.

```
    <tr>
<td>
<span class="text-danger font-weight-bold"><br/>
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in <b>/srv/www/chroot/site05/web/app/bootstrap.php</b> on line <b>159</b><br/>
wrestlers_club</span> INFO1<br/>
<span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">wrestlers_birthday</span> INFO2<br/><br/>
<span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">wrestlers_licence_number</span> wrestlers_licence_no_licence<br/>
<span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">wrestlers_club_dl</span> wrestlers_licence_no_dl                                                
                    </td>
```

My code looks now:

```
info = soup.find('div', id='content')
club = info.findAll('span')
for clubs in club:
 test = clubs.text
 print(test)
```

And the Result is:

**Notice**:

```
 Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in /srv/www/chroot/site05/web/app/bootstrap.php on line 159
```

wrestlers_club

wrestlers_birthday

wrestlers_licence_number

wrestlers_club_dl

How can I extract the data behind wreslters_club `(INFO1)` and wrestlers_birthday `(INFO2)`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share the website? You might better use Selenium to do this for you

Comment: I added the link into the description ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following `Css selector` and `find_next_sibling(text=True)`

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    res=requests.get("https://swisswrestling.ch/wrestlers?id=91")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('span.text-danger:nth-of-type(1)').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
    print(soup.select_one('span.text-danger:nth-of-type(2)').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
```

**Output**:

```
RC Willisau Lions
29 (1990)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? I used the link you posted and it extracts the required information.

```
import requests
import re
import lxml
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
url = 'https://swisswrestling.ch/wrestlers?id=91'

strx = requests.get(url).text
regex = r"(wrestlers_club|wrestlers_birthday) (.*)\n"
soup = bs(strx, 'lxml')


for i in soup.find_all('td'):
    print (*re.findall(regex,i.text), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
('wrestlers_club', 'RC Willisau Lions')
('wrestlers_birthday', '29 (1990)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it gave me the result you requested:

```
     info = soup.find('div', id='content')
     club = info.select('#content-element-94 > div.row.border.mx-0 > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)')
     for clubs in club:
       test = clubs.text
       print(test)
```

output:

```
       wrestlers_club RC Willisau Lions
       wrestlers_birthday 29 (1990)
       wrestlers_licence_number wrestlers_licence_no_licence
       wrestlers_club_dl wrestlers_licence_no_dl
```